# What is the best way to wait for function output for no longer than certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, synchronous

I have two functions. Say, one does some complex logic and another wraps the former to provide either result of computation or, after `t` seconds and in case there's no output, an error message.

So if I do the following

```
var complex = function () {
    // do complex computation
};

var output = function (compute) {
    return compute();
};

output(complex);
```

then it runs for too long because the process in case `complex` takes too much time as it's being executed synchronously. I need to throw an error message if it takes longer than `t`. Terminating the execution of `complex` isn't necessary, but returning any value from `output` in no longer time than `t` is the main point. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: In modern code terminology you are asking about something called 'promises'. jQuery has it built it for example - it basically make code wait until they receive a success or failure callback.

Comment: @sidonaldson This only works for asynchronous tasks

Comment: as Denys Séguret says, I think webworkers might be a good solution to your problem

Comment: @DenysSéguret / edi9999 not true. It doesn't matter. It makes any task or function asynchronous.

Comment: @sidonaldson And how would the promise help you halt a synchronous local task ? There's no magic in promises, they can't do that.

Comment: @DenysSéguret now you are making assumptions. The poster did not say they want to halt a local task. In fact what is a local task in javascript? A promise can be used for absolutely anything and can easily be coded in such a way that you can terminate other functions. It is also a simple solution to this question as the poster just wants to return an error it it times out

Comment: @sidonaldson See "synchronously".

Comment: OP, can you confirm your task is really a synchronous local computation as I understood ?

Comment: Yes, it's synchronous local task.

Comment: He has just updated the post! :p I would love to see more code as this case appears as if you are writing JS that synchronously blocks the whole script. However, your solution is the correct one if so. Sorry for the confusion @DenysSéguret

Comment: OP, the "halting problem" has a very precise meaning, it doesn't apply here

Comment: Got it about halting-problem. The problem's still not solved, though.

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches are possible in javascript in the browser for a synchronous locally done computation:

**1)** break the computation in smaller computation units and check the time between units. This means the algorithm has to be adapted.

**2)** defer the computation to a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) (which runs in a separate thread) and [`terminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Terminating_a_worker) it if it takes too much time.

Comment: The complex computation cannot be divided into blocks. It's a solid synchronous process that, if necessary, can run in a separate thread. Worker is a good suggestion but I run the code on server in Node environment (didn't put this tag, my fault, fixed that).

Comment: Are you *sure* there's no loop inside your computation code where you could test for a boolean `stopped` ?

Comment: Nope. I can't control this function. I can only execute it as is, without any modifications.